# Лишний знак?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста. В предложении явная пауза, но по правилам вроде бы знак не положен.   Прохладный ветер гладил его лицо() заботливо, успокаивающе, уговаривая остаться здесь навсегда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире можно поставить. Только не запятую.

Answer (score 0):

Тире допустимо как авторский знак.

Comment: Именно авторский. А если без авторства, то не нужно никакого знака.